# NG-Repeat returns empty rows

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to use ng-repeat to print out an array in an HTML list. The items of the list are showing correctly, but the rows are empty.

I tried different angularjs versions, jquery versions, but it did not work. If I use ng-bind it shows the data on the html page fine.

index.js

```
var app = angular.module('programsApp', []);

app.controller('programsController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.programs = [1, 2, 3];
    console.log($scope.programs);
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Index</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../index.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="programsApp" ng-controller="programsController">

    <h1>Current Programs</h1>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in programs">{{x}}</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The console prints the array fine from the index.js, and no errors

```
3) [1, 2, 3]0: 11: 22: 3length: 3__proto__: Array(0)
```

The html page shows only

```
Current Programs
*
*
*
```

so it shows three li but nothing in them

here is the code from inspect element

```
<ul>
<!-- ngRepeat: x in programs -->
<li ng-repeat="x in programs" class="ng-scope"></li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: x in programs -->
<li ng-repeat="x in programs" class="ng-scope"></li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: x in programs -->
<li ng-repeat="x in programs" class="ng-scope"></li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: x in programs -->
</ul>
```

Thank you.

---

UPDATE: the issue was in the express configurations, removed:

```
app.engine('html', engines.mustache);
```

and changed it to:

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

solved the issue!

Thank you [dacre-denny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8526705/dacre-denny)

Comment: Seems like your code is working correctly here?

Comment: It is not printing the value of the array

Comment: Here's what your code produces at my end : https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH5qm.png

Comment: It shows empty rows on my end. I tested on Ubuntu chrome, and Firefox. As well as Mac Chrome. https://imgur.com/a/eAYo7NL ... I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it ... this is part of bigger nodeJs program, so I'm starting it on a localhost server "node app.js"?

Comment: Are you noticing any console errors?

Comment: Maybe another part of the code is changing things in the DOM, the code you provided _should_ work just fine

Comment: No errors in console. The console prints out the array completely normal.

Comment: I have the exact code on the machine now, I got rid of everything else. The only thing different is I'm starting that as node/express application. Anything to do with the view engine and these stuff?

Comment: Maybe it's a caching issue, try loading the page from Incognito tab

Comment: Same thing. It is weird though it is repeating the item correctly, but the value is empty. If you see the last code I provided above, when I do inspect element after it renders the li is empty.

Comment: One idea might be to check the list is non-empty before rendering (usually not necessary, but might be a quirk with you particular browser/environment) - have posted an answer below. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue may be a side-effect of your `<ul>` list monumentally existing with no `<li>` elements prior to the first scope digest. Consider adding a check that only allows the `<ul>` list to render when the `programs` list is non-empty:

```js
angular
  .module('programsApp', [])
  .controller('programsController', function($scope) {

    $scope.programs = [1, 2, 3];
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Index</title>
  <!-- Reverted to a slightly older version of angularjs -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="programsApp" ng-controller="programsController">
  <h1>Current Programs</h1>

  <!-- Consider adding a check to only render if programs list is non-empty -->
  <ul ng-if="programs.length > 0">
    <li ng-repeat="item in programs">
      <!-- Consider nesting the {{ item }} in an element within <li> -->  
      <span>{{ item }}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same issue.

Comment: ```
app.engine('html', engines.mustache);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(expressSanitizer());
```
this is the express configurations, if it makes a differenace?

Comment: Thanks for that - `engines.mustache` may be a problem. Can you remove that? Also, is the html above being served from your `public` static directory?

Comment: The html is under "views" directory, which is outside the "public" directory, and the "public" directory is serving the css, and js files.

Removing the engines.mustache won't load the html pages any more "Error: Cannot find module 'html'"

Comment: Worked! thank you a million! changed the engine to this "app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);"

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help :)